# Overclocking i5-7400 (non-K) CPU

Tags: cpu, overclocking

I have a Kaby Lake i5-7400 CPU on a Gigabyte GA-Z170XP-SLI motherboard. Recently, I decided to delve into overclocking, and found that I was able to increase the CPU multiplier from the default of 30 to 33 then 35 without stability issues. CPU benchmark seems to reflect appropriate speed increases, so all seems well. ([CPU-Z Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krAoM.png))

My question is, how is this possible? Everything I read seems to suggest that only the "K" Intel CPUs have an unlocked multiplier, and mine is definitely not a "K" series CPU.

Am I doing something wrong? Should I change the multiplier back to 30 and use BCLK to overclock?

Comment: Apparently, non-K CPUs are capable of "[turbo boost](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html)" which acts like automatic, on-demand overclocking. Perhaps, when I increased the multiplier, it's forcing the CPU into constant turbo mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting, you are not supposed to be able to overclock it, but if it works, and it's stable, and you know the risks in over clocking, no reason not to.

From chatter on the Internet it appears that some of these units - with older microcode can be overclocked - so you probably want to make sure you don't update the microcode if this ability is important to you.

Comment: I routinely install all Windows updates, and the BIOS/UEFI firmware is also up to date. Have not installed a dedicated Intel microcode update, but I believe these were included in the recent windows update patches. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

i have the same processor and i cant change the value of the multiplier but there something a heard a few years ago is that intel produces a batch of cpu's at same time and some of them cameout a little bit better of the default project and they sell as "black edition" or something but it apears that some of thouse black edition processors are not fully tested and for some random reasons they can be found in the middle of the standard ones, back in the days i had a i5 4400U wich is very weaky notebook processor so i was capable of changing its multiplier and make 3.75GHz in all cores intil its overheat and shutdown... its pretty rare to see one of thouse, i guess your lucky.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).